# How do I position dynamically added ImageView's so they are limited to 3 in a row on a grid?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am creating an application and one feature is to allow its users to take photos and view them as thumbnails before submitting them. I have managed to get the camera to pull up, take a photo and then display the photos in a LinearLayout. The problem I'm having is I can't get them to position nicely, I want them in a grid that only allows 3 images side-by-side from which they would move onto a new line.

Here is my class:

```
package com.example.dentdevils.ui.HomeLinks;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.dentdevils.R;

public class AddPhotosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_photos);

        this.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearPhoto);
        Button takePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTakePhoto);

        takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                        imageView = new ImageView(AddPhotosActivity.this);
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
                        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                        linearLayout.addView(imageView);
                    }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
        {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission denied. The app must have permissions to use your camera.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the images spread out like so (because of adding the weight parameter):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqQV5.jpg

How would I limit the number of images to 3 before it then creates a new LinearLayout to hold the next 3 images? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a RecyclerView with GridLayout Manager and set the span as 3

In XML,

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/photo_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="3"/>
```

Along with it, you will have to create layout of each item and an adapter to populate the recyclerview

Simple layout for each Item in recyclerView,

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photo_image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

To set the images, make a list of images that you want to display and pass it to the adapter of the recyclerview and it will populate the recycler view with the images.

RecyclerView Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView